# Add/Change Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need help
My dataframe was imported like this.

| 1 | shirt |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | hat |
| 3 | shoes |

But the column name is already information.

I would like to change the columns to:

| Code | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | shirt |
| 2 | hat |
| 3 | shoes |

Can u help me?
Gratz

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pd.read_csv` (or `pd.read_excel`), use `header` and `names` parameters:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, names=['Code', 'product'])
print(df)

# Output
   Code product
0     1   shirt
1     2     hat
2     3   shoes
```

Content of `data.csv`:

```
1,shirt
2,hat
3,shoes
```

Comment: Hi! I use a pdf file, using tabula.